# Why do I get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for bean 'com.mypackage.service.blog.BlogService'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, autowired

In spring, I am trying to resolve an `Unresolved Bean Exception` when I try to do from my `BlogController`:

```
@Autowired BlogService blogService;
```

- I am using `org.springframework.stereotype.Service` service annotation.
- My `ApiApplication` application class is annotated with `@ComponentScan("com.mypackage")`.
- The service implementation is annotation with `@Service` and is in `com.mypackage.service.blog.BlogService"`
- The service can't be `Autowired`, but it's `@Repository` used by the service and located in `com.mypackage.repository.blog.BlogRepository` can be imported by the controller.

My application class looks like this :

```
package com.mypackage;

import com.mypackage.core.Core;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({
        "com.mypackage",
        "com.mypackage.service.blog"
})
public class ApiApplication {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.useSlf4jLogging();
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
        logger.info("Application started!");
    }

}
```

This is my `com.mypackage.controller.blog.BlogController`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/blogs")
public class BlogController {

  @Autowired
  private BlogService blogService;

  @PostMapping
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  Long create(@RequestBody Blog blog) {
    blogService.insert(blog);
    return blog.getId();
  }
```

My `com.mypackage.service.blog.BlogService` class:

```
public interface BlogService extends CrudService<Blog, Long> {
}
```

My `com.mypackage.service.blog.impl.BlogServiceImpl` class:

```
@Service
@UserManagementTx
public class BlogServiceImpl extends AbstractCrudService<BlogRepository, Blog, Long> {

    @Autowired
    public BlogServiceImpl(BlogRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
    }

}
```

I have turned debug log and I am trying to find some hint why the Service is not imported.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mypackage.service.blog.BlogService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Should I take some particular classpath to DEBUG and the other to INFO ? I don't see the services creation and classpath in my current DEBUG logs.

Comment: Info given is not enough for me to help you, please show us your ApiApplication class including the annotations.

Comment: @MinjunYu I've just shared it, do you see anything useful ? I've added twice the scan to be more explicit.

Comment: @SpringBootApplication should work becasue your ApiApplication class is at the root of the package. Adding another componentScan is redundant. Where is your Service implementation located.

Comment: `@ComponentScan` is not required here as it part of `@SpringBootAppication`. Also add other classes too (controller and service).

Comment: `Also add other classes too (controller and service)` : what do you mean ?

Comment: `BlogService, BlogController ` and the class where you are trying to inject this service. I just need to see configuration part of these classes.

Comment: There is no configuration in Controller and Service, only annotation. What do you need to see exactly ?

Comment: Could you please add `BlogService` code snipped in the question.

Comment: Yeah, i am looking for those annotations to see what's went wrong there. Your project structure looks good, so we need to check controller and service.

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point `#1`

`@ComponentScan` is not needed here, just remove it from your main class of application i.e. `ApiApplication` and it will work.

Point `#2`

As we can see `BlogServiceImpl` does not implement `BlogService` which means there is no concrete implementation of `BlogService` hence `Bean` cannot be created.

You need to implement `BlogServiceImpl` the interface `BlogService` to tell the spring that `BlogServiceImpl` is the implementation of `BlogService`

```
public class BlogServiceImpl implements BlogService
```

and **I would highly recommend you to follow package structure** [As per spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) then you will not need to include `@ComponentScan` to get created `Bean`s.

```
com
 +- example
     +- myproject
         +- Application.java
         |
         +- domain
         |   +- Customer.java
         |   +- CustomerRepository.java
         |
         +- service
         |   +- CustomerService.java
         |
         +- web
             +- CustomerController.java
```

Comment: I think this is what my annotation does + @SpringBootApplication should already be sufficient as mentioned by @antontupy. Apparently the beanDefinitionsNames contain them but for some reason, the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` still occure

Comment: If I decided not to use this structure this is because my project is composed of an app that use core modules and addons. Addons have their own namespace under `com.example.myproject.sampleaddon` and they also have `domain/service/controller` that can be used by the projet. The complexity in these addons can require to create a subfolder in each of these folders. Spring documentation you linked only says how to do if you are building a simple application.

Comment: @BigDong I've just tried your project on my machine. and I just removed the `@ComponentScan({
        "com.mypackage",
        "com.mypackage.service.blog"
})` from the main application, it worked. Please do this also and let me know if it worked for you too. Then I'll add my reasoning in the answer.

Comment: I have removed the `@ComponentScan` and It says `Field blogService in com.mypackage.controller.blog.BlogController required a bean of type 'com.mypackage.service.common.BlogService' that could not be found.` (Notice that I moved BlogService in `common` because all the service in `common` can be autowired, apparently there is something that prevent the creation of the service which is not the classpath.)

Comment: If your `main` class in `com.mypackage` then all the classess under packages  `com.mypackage.blah.blah` will be eligible to `Bean` creation.

Comment: This is what I assume, the doc is generally right, but it may be wrong because every version comes with bugs. I've added service, service implementation and controller for the blog in my question. Do you see why my beans doesn't get created ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use class below to view which beans was created in context. Mey be this will help.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.Arrays;

@Component
class BeansLogger {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BeansLogger.class);

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public BeansLogger(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        final String[] beanDefinitionNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanDefinitionNames);
        LOGGER.debug("Registered beans: {}", Arrays.asList(beanDefinitionNames));
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see in `beanDefinitionNames` that there is `blogRepository` and `blogServiceImpl`, so why is it not created ?